# Loading Images from JSON to Xcode

Tags: objective-c, sql, xcode, json

I having a bit difficulty loading images from a json file into UIImage - Table Cells in Xcode. I tried to load the images from the server into a NSArray then populating the table view UIImage cells. Is there something that I am missing here?

Image are located on a SQL server.

Thanks for the help.

Here is the server output from the PHP into Xcode. (cover_image)

```
(
    "13497074790148.jpeg",
    "13494650900147.png",
    "13494606630147.png",
    "13494605220147.jpeg",
    "13494602920147.jpeg",
    "13494601850147.jpeg",
    "13491916300147.jpeg"
)
```

Here is the code in Xcode

```
NSArray *itemsimages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[results valueForKeyPath:@"cover_image"]];
self.itemImages = itemsimages;
```

Here is the code in table cells

```
UIImage *imageitm = [UIImage imageNamed: [self.itemImages objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
cell.itmImage.image = imageitm;
return cell;
```

Comment: imageNamed: is designed for images in your app bundle. Where are the images located?

Comment: the images are located in a SQL server. I am trying to retrieve them from there.

Comment: @PaulLalonde the image are on a SQL server. I am trying to implement SDWebImage to get those images. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @exlux15 The best practices is to be retrieving those images via some sort of webservice and not directly from the SQL server.  Only the webservice should be talking to the SQL server.

Comment: @PaulLalonde Thanks. At the moment I have a request sent from Xcode to a URL(PHP with GET methods). The PHP file gets the require information and then XCode gets the server output from the PHP. How would I change that process implement the webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have those images stored locally so it doesn't have any images to display. I suggest using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to provide asyncronous image loading from remote location + caching mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can SDWebImage be used to get images from SQL or just a URL?

Comment: If you would go to the link I provided, you will get all the info you need on implementing it. You will have to provide a baseURL. For example http://www.myServer.com/123565643.jpeg will contain you image.

Comment: I am trying to get the entire column of image data in the SQL table. Would this baseURL get all those data?

Comment: If you can open the baseUrl+photoName in a browser and it displays the image you wanted, you cand use it. Else no. This is for all the images. What I mean is that you need the url for the image to load it this way. Should be easy enough for you to get the urls for the images.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *img = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *websiteDetails = (NSArray *) [json objectForKey:@"logos"];

    for(int count=0; count<[websiteDetails count]; count++)
    {
        NSDictionary *websiteInfo = (NSDictionary *) [websiteDetails objectAtIndex:count];
        imagefile = (NSString *) [websiteInfo objectForKey:@"image_file"];
        if([imagefile length]>0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Imagefile URL is: %@",imagefile);
            [img addObject:imagefile];
        }
    }
    //NSarray listofURL
    listofURL = img;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    //this will start the image loading in bg
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[listofURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

        //this will set the image when loading is finished
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
        });
    });
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a proper url in json response or you can store the common part of the url in the code itself and append it later with the image name returned from server.
I did as follows in the same condition

```
    __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary *dict = ((NSDictionary *) result)[@"result"];

    NSString *url = dict[@"imageURL"];

    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    [_buttonImageView setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where data is the response returned from server.

Comment: You should do this async especially as it is going to be used in a tableview

Comment: yeah you are right. But i just meant to give the idea.. rest is upto the developer.